# Scroll event on IOS with jquery

Tags: jquery, directive, scrolltop

I am trying to create a menu that hide on mobile when scrolling down. I need to listen for the scroll event and apply classes thusly.

For some reason I am having trouble listening to the scroll on ios, but android it is fine.

```
 ("*").scroll(function () {
           //code
            }
```

any idea what I could use to resolve this?

Comment: have you tried "onscroll"? IOS handles scrolls a little different to android

Comment: Just figured it out, "use strict" seems to stop jqueries ontouchmove from working. So, i'll close this

Answer (score 0):

Removed "Use Strict" from code -- prevented some functions from working.